# Discord.py call task immediately

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, discord.py

I'm trying to add an API (Django/DRF) to my discord.py bot.  Currently the best solution I have is to add a task from the endpoint then return a 202.  The task then executes... eventually.

Django Rest Framework viewset.py`:

```
async def connect_client(self, request, client):
    print('Connecting client...')
    from discordbot import music_player
    await music_player.connect()

@action(methods=['get'], detail=False)
def connect(self, request, pk=None):
    from discordbot import client
    client.loop.create_task(self.connect_client(request, client))
    return Response(status=202)
```

This works, and it does do what the task is supposed to do.  But when it executes seems to be entirely reliant on how fast the event loop polls.

The task seems to be created immediately, but it takes anywhere from 1 to 10 seconds to run (seemingly at random).

Can I either change how fast the event loop polls (to every 500ms or 1000ms), or have it create a task and call it immediately?

Comment: `client.loop.create_task(self.connect_client(request, client))` - This calls `self.connect_client(request, client)` *now*, and then `client.loop.create_task` with whatever the `connect_client` call returns. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the end goal was to have that async task executed immediately (since DRF doesn't allow for async methods as an endpoint), with the contents of `connect_client` getting run asap.